# some tags are not visible in git log but visible in git tag

Tags: github, git-tag

We newly created a long term support branch from our `develop` branch last sprint, say it is called `v2021.1.LTS`, after I checkout `v2021.1.LTS` branch, I did a `git log` and from the results, I noticed 6 latest version tags are missing (v2.114.2-rc.3~v2.114.2-rc.8 are missing, the latest tag I could see was v2.114.2-rc.2), but I could see all of them via `git tag`; after I brought it out to other senior developers, they told me:

> We created this `v2021.1.LTS` branch last sprint and it was the same as
> `develop`. The current sprint is going to be the first sprint when
> `v2021.1.LTS` and `develop` diverge so that the 6 latest version tags are
> tracking the `develop` branch instead of this `v2021.1.LTS` branch.

I am very confused by this explanation. Can anyone please elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by "I noticed 6 latest version tags are missing"? Were those tags created ahead of the LTS tag?

Comment: @AshishSantikari, after the creation of this LTS tag. What do I mean by missing: I could see those tags via git tag, but those tags are not visible via git log. The latest tag I could see on the LTS branch vis git log is v2.114.2-rc.2, but I was expecting to see v2.114.2-rc.3~v2.114.2-rc.8 as well.

Comment: try `git log --no-walk --tags --pretty="%H %d" --decorate=full`

Comment: @AshishSantikari, magic, I could see everything, including those missing tags and their commit hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --no-walk --tags --pretty="%H %d" --decorate=full
```